# Windows Enterprise - Proxy without auth

Tags: proxy

Is it possible to run a Windows-based enterprise and have people authenticate with the proxy server using AD credentials without ever having to type credentials in?

This also includes using PowerShell or command-line tools. i.e. all internet traffic is authenticated automatically, or at least can be traced back to a person.

If so, how? What are the high-level systems and steps?

I'm a programmer and in any sizable company, proxy auth has been a nightmare for the team, expensive friction, sometimes a complete barrier to "cooler" start-up technologies.

Answer (score -1):

Kerberos authentication should work fine in Windows-AD-based enterprise.